# skin become dark after render in cyle render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, mesh, node-editor

I just used a blender. I need to ask why the skin turns black after switching from the material display to the rendering display, even though all the light is already bright, here SS. Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could it be because you are using a mix shader with the texture that mixes it 50% with black? Maybe slide the Factor to 0 (or maybe 1.0).

Comment: It's because you have unconnected Shader socket in your mix shader (it is black) and probably because you feed normal map data into displacement socket, and because your normal map texture is set to color and not non-color-data.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I have found a solution ... the texture must use alpha color.. i will edit this question

Comment: Rather than making answer an edit to question and marking it "SOLVED",  please add an answer.

Comment: sorry im new using this... thx for remind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIX! here the node before.
[image]
After
[image]

Comment: This makes little sense. I would suggest learning what the nodes do before using them. If you removed the Mix Shader node you would only have the Diffuse BSDF that would have the same effect.

Comment: yeah i'm still learning now